# Basic GeoJSON test with OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

I'm new to openlayers. I already made a few tests with marks and it worked fine. I was trying to undestand the GeoJSON features and tryed to replicate the example from openlayers:
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/geojson.html?q=geojson
I should be missing something basic, using this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nf213axk/2/) i'm getting this error:

```
RegularShape.js:362 Uncaught TypeError: this.fill_.getColor is not a function
    at e.draw_ (RegularShape.js:362)
    at e.render (RegularShape.js:325)
    at e [as constructor] (RegularShape.js:138)
    at new e (Circle.js:37)
    at window.onload ((index):184)
```

Thanks

Comment: `vectorSource.addFeature(new ol.Feature(new ol.style.Circle([5e6, 7e6], 1e6)));` should be `vectorSource.addFeature(new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Circle([5e6, 7e6], 1e6)));`

Comment: Thanks Mike, I missed that one